# Position of the component's label in Circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz

I have this circuit created with circuitikz that simply represent a current generator with the direction of the current and its label.

```
\begin{circuitikz}[american]
  \draw (0,0) to[ioosource, i_=$i_{in}$] +(0,-2) node[ground]{};
\end{circuitikz}
```

The result is this:

[image]

But I would like to have the label of the current next to the current generator symbol like in this case:

```
\begin{circuitikz}[american]
  \draw (0,0) to[ioosource, l_=$i_{in}$] +(0,-2) node[ground]{};
\end{circuitikz}
```

[image]

But as you can see if I do in this way the arrow of the current is no more present.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: please see the answer below -- adjust `xshift` and `yshift` to taste

Comment: would you like to accept and upvote the answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By use of annotation `a` (or label `l`) and invisible current flow symbol label:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[american]
  \draw (0,0) to[ioosource, a=$i_{\mathrm{in}}$, i=~]   ++(0,-2) node[ground]{};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}[american]
        \draw (0,0) to[ioosource, i=$$]node[xshift=-4pt,yshift=0.7cm,left]{$i_{in}$} +(0,-2) node[ground]{};
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

**second method -- with angle and label**

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}[american]
        \draw (0,0) to[ioosource, i=$$]node[outer sep=4mm, label=120:$i_{in}$]{} +(0,-2) node[ground]{};
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly what is asked, but as a **totally shameful cheat**:

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[american]
    \draw (0,0) to[voosource, v_=$i_{in}$, voltage=straight] +(0,-2) node[ground]{};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

...cheat that, for cleanliness, I would hide <s>under the carpet</s> in a style:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\tikzset{ioosource external i/.style={
        voosource, v_={#1}, voltage=straight,
    }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[american]
    \draw (0,0) to[ioosource external i=$i_{in}$] +(0,-2) node[ground]{};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

(same output)